# How to set a TCL variable as a varible in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, tcl

So my goal is to take a variable that is in my TCL file and pass it to my shell script for it to be able to use. Right now I am able to echo to get the result of my variable but I cannot for some reason set that result to a variable in my bash script.

Here is an example of my TCL script:

```
set file_status "C"
```

Here is what I have for my bash script:

```
echo 'source example.tcl; foreach _v {file_status } {puts "\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh
file_status='source example.tcl; foreach _v {file_status } {puts "\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh
echo $file_status
```

So the first echo statement above works but after I set the file_status variable for some reason the second echo statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in general requires very complex code; Tcl variables are capable of holding arbitrary data (including full binary data) and don't have length restrictions, whereas Shell is a lot more restricted. But it's possible to do something for the common cases where the values are plain text without NULs. (`C` would be an excellent example of such a value.)

When passing to a subprocess, by far the easiest way is to use an environment variable:

```
set the_status "C"
set env(file_status) $the_status
exec bash -c {echo "file status is $file_status"} >@stdout
```

That has length restrictions, but it's extremely easy.

If you're sending the variable to some other process, your best bet is to write a little script (here, I'm sending it to `stdout`):

```
puts [format {file_status='%s'} [string map {"'" "'\''"} $the_status]]
```

That is producing a script that just sets the variable. (`string map` is turning single quotes into something that works inside single quotes; everything else doesn't need conversion like that.) You run the script in the shell with `eval` or `source`/`.` (depending on whether it is in a string or in a file).

Very large data should be moved around inside a file or via a pipe. It needs *much* more thought in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would output shell syntax from Tcl and source it into your running shell:

Given

```sh
$ echo 'source example.tcl; foreach var {file_status} {puts "$var=\"[set $var]\""}' | tclsh
file_status="C"
```

then

```sh
source <(echo 'source example.tcl; foreach var {file_status} {puts "$var=\"[set $var]\""}' | tclsh)
declare -p file_status
```

outputs

```
declare -- file_status="C"
```

---

Using /bin/sh, you could:

```sh
var_file=$(mktemp)
echo ... | tclsh > "$var_file"
source "$var_file"
rm "$var_file"
```

Comment: When I run this line: source <(echo 'source example.tcl; foreach var {file_status} {puts "$var=\"[set $var]\""}' | tclsh)

I get unexpected token error `('

Comment: What is your shell? Is it /bin/sh? The process substitution `<(...)` is bash syntax.

Comment: And you don't even need to know the variable names beforehand if you find the difference in `info vars` before and after `source`.